# Slide out menu with categories crashes by saying "NSCFString objectAtIndex" while using APExpandableTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I am using a third party library to show drop down cells for a slide out menu with an arrow to open the subcategories. Using `APExpandableTableView` I get an error which says:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8612e834f0".

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.expandableTableView.expandableTableViewDelegate = self;

    [self customSetup];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void)customSetup
{
    newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *apiURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/products/categories",mainURL];

    OAuth1Legged *OAuth = [[OAuth1Legged alloc] init];

    NSString *finalURL = [OAuth generateGetURL:apiURL];



    [OAuth getJsonResponse:finalURL success:^(NSDictionary *responseDict)
     {
         dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             self.dataModelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

             NSMutableDictionary *productCategories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
             productCategories = [responseDict objectForKey:@"product_categories"];

             NSLog(@"Response %@ ", productCategories);

             self.responseJSON = responseDict;
             if ([self.responseJSON isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){ //Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
                 dictionaryArray= [self.responseJSON objectForKey:@"product_categories"];
                 if ([dictionaryArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
                     //Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
                     for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dictionaryArray) {

                         CategoryBO *categoryBO = [[CategoryBO alloc] init];
                         categoryBO.categoryName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
                         categoryBO.categoryProductId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
                         categoryBO.categoryParentID = [dictionary objectForKey:@"parent"];

                         [newArray addObject:categoryBO];

                     }
                 }
             }
             NSLog(@"Data Array: %@",newArray);

             for(int i = 0; i<[newArray count];i++)
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",[[newArray objectAtIndex:i] categoryName]);
                 [self.dataModelArray addObject:[[newArray objectAtIndex:i] categoryName]] ;
             }

             NSLog(@"Data %@", self.dataModelArray);
             [self.expandableTableView reloadData];




         });

     } failure:^(NSError *error) {

     }];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)expandableTableView:(APExpandableTableView *)tableView numberOfChildrenForGroupAtIndex:(NSInteger)groupIndex {
    return [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] count] - 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfGroupsInExpandableTableView:(APExpandableTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.dataModelArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)expandableTableView:(APExpandableTableView *)tableView cellForChildAtIndex:(NSInteger)childIndex groupIndex:(NSInteger)groupIndex {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SampleChildCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.expandableTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] objectAtIndex:childIndex + 1];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)expandableTableView:(APExpandableTableView *)tableView cellForGroupAtIndex:(NSInteger)groupIndex {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SampleGroupCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.expandableTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] objectAtIndex:0];

    return cell;
}

- (void)expandableTableView:(APExpandableTableView *)tableView deleteChildAtIndex:(NSInteger)childIndex groupIndex:(NSInteger)groupIndex {
    [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] removeObjectAtIndex:childIndex + 1];
}

- (void)expandableTableView:(APExpandableTableView *)tableView moveChildAtIndex:(NSInteger)sourceIndex toIndex:(NSInteger)destinationIndex groupIndex:(NSInteger)groupIndex {
    NSString *moveObject = [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] objectAtIndex:sourceIndex + 1];
    [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndex + 1];
    [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] insertObject:moveObject atIndex:destinationIndex + 1];
}

- (void)expandableTableView:(APExpandableTableView *)tableView moveGroupAtIndex:(NSInteger)sourceIndex toIndex:(NSInteger)destinationIndex {
    NSMutableArray *moveObject = [self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndex];
    [self.dataModelArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndex];
    [self.dataModelArray insertObject:moveObject atIndex:destinationIndex];
}
```

Comment: in which line did you get Error?

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex] objectAtIndex:childIndex + 1];
this

Comment: check your Array data. if your array is getting nil then use IF and Else condition

Comment: the array data is not nil. It has 3 objects. Electronics, Hard Drives, and Mobiles

Comment: What id group index?   Use Indexpath.row

Comment: The error is indicating that you are calling the method `objectAtIndex:` on an object that is of type `NSString`, and not an array type. When you create your `dataModelArray` you add an object from another array after calling `categoryName` on that object (which I assume is returning a string). So the items in the `dataModelArray` are strings. You should be able to use `cell.textLabel.text = [[self.dataModelArray objectAtIndex:groupIndex];` to get the item in the array.

Comment: I got it.. I had to pass an array to the objectAtIndex and not a String value